# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.BuiltInConverters on android 4.4

Tags: android, retrofit, android-4.4-kitkat

The version of retrofit is 2.0.0 beta2.
It works fine on Android 5.0,but "new Retrofit.Builder() " throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.BuiltInConverters on android 4.4.

Logcat:
[image]

Build gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "***"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 4
    versionName "2.0.3"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
    }
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
}
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile project(':searchview')
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v14:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
    compile 'com.commit451:PhotoView:1.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Similar to [NoClassDefFoundError: retrofit.RestAdapter$Builder When Using retrofit-1.6.1 on Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24677527/running-android-app-produces-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-retrofit-restadapte)
Any help would be appreciated!

---------2015/12/16---------------
I solved it by following this answer:[add the multidex support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28722345/1263423)

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya,updated.

Comment: Take a look on minifyEnabled flag - it is true - so ProGuard will be run when you build your app, It can be the reason

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak,I have tried to set minifyEnabled  to false,but it still not solve the problem.

Comment: @wangqi060934 please attach some example code which reproduces this issue

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak,I think the bug is caused as my project exceed the 65k limit and Dalvik limits apps to a single classes.dex bytecode file per APK.